# Retrieve by lambda query and bind to DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, lambda

I've created a `dataTable` ,

```
   private static DataTable GenerateDataTable()
    {
        DataTable _tempSalaryCalculatoin = new DataTable();
        _tempSalaryCalculatoin.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
        _tempSalaryCalculatoin.Columns.Add("NRC", typeof(string));
        _tempSalaryCalculatoin.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string));
        _tempSalaryCalculatoin.Columns.Add("Rank", typeof(string));
        _tempSalaryCalculatoin.Columns.Add("Deduction", typeof(string));
        _tempSalaryCalculatoin.Columns.Add("MontlySalary", typeof(string));
        _tempSalaryCalculatoin.Columns.Add("NetSalary", typeof(string));

    }
```

And I have Database-Table (`Employee`) likes

```
ID    NRC     FullName    FatherName    SpouseName       Rank
1     xxx     xxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxxx      xxxxxx
2     xxx     xxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxxx      xxxxxx
3     xxx     xxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxxx      xxxxxx
4     xxx     xxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxxx      xxxxxx
```

Data are just for example .

I retrieve this data using `lambda query` ,

```
 DataTable _dtSC = GenerateDataTable(); // Generated by the above method
 var _empData  = db.DBInsContext.Employees.Where(x => x.Rank == "xxx" ).ToList();
```

I want to convert this `_empData` to DataTable `_dtSc` .
Notice that > DataTable `_dtSc` has only seven columns .
I want to leave the columns (which are not exist in `Employee` table) as Null or Empty .Such as (Deduction , MontlySalary and NetSalary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most efficient is using a loop. Note that LINQ is a query- and not a modify-tool:

```
foreach(var emp in _empData)
{
    var newRow = _dtSC.Rows.Add();
    newRow.SetField("ID", emp.ID);
    // and so on ...
    // you are free to not initialize a field like Deduction
}
```

Comment: cant he use query.CopyToDataTable();?

Comment: @NitinVarpe: No, since that supports only `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Altough there is [a workaround](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx) that uses reflection to use `CopyToDataTable` on anything i wouldn't use that approach.

Comment: I think it would be better for him to do db.DBInsContext.Employees.AsEnumerable(), is it or not?

Comment: @NitinVarpe: I'm not sure, maybe he needs that list somewhere. However, that's out of scope of this question isn't it?

Comment: +1 for Tim , your code perfectly works ! And I will not forget to accept your answer :)  @Nitin Varpe , Can you post your answer , I want to know about your method too :) Thanks !